# A conceptual problem in group theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

As we all know that in group $S_n$ every pair of distinct  disjoint cycles commute .my doubt is is it reverse all true,mean if a pair of distinct cycles commute ,then they have to be disjoint??.i tried to find examples where distinct cycles commute but not disjoint,but fail to do so

Comment: If they are both the same cycle, then they must commute. So maybe exclude that?

Comment: $(1\ 2\ 3)$ commutes with $(1\ 3\ 2).$ More generally consider $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1},$ or $\sigma^m$ and $\sigma^n,$ where $\sigma$ is a cycle and $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime to the order of $\sigma.$

Comment: Wow, great question. +1

Comment: @bof does it really matter that m and n are realtive prime.???i think in ur comment it is not required .

Comment: @Eklavya I did not say that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. I said that they are relatively prime to the order of $\sigma$. If $m$ is not relatively prime to the order of $\sigma$ then $\sigma^n$ may not be a cycle.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, the answer is that cycles $\sigma$ and $\tau$ commute if and only if either:

(i) $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are disjoint; or

(ii) $\sigma$ is a power of $\tau$ and $\tau$ is a power of $\sigma$.

In case (ii), this implies that they have the same order and hence the same length, and they must both be cycles on the same set of points.