# Necessary and sufficient conditions for elements of $S_n$ to commute

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, symmetric-groups

Is there a general theory for elements of $S_n$ to commute? For example, it is common knowledge that if two elements are disjoint, then they commute. However, this is not a necessary condition. It is said [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554319/a-conceptual-problem-in-group-theory) that cycles permute if and only if they are powers of one another or disjoint. This does not work for permutations that are not cycles, e.g. $(12)(34)$ and $(12)$.

Comment: Your (counter)example is very close to being OK: the cycles of $(12)(34)$ and $(12)(3)(4)$  can be aligned so that they are powers  of each other. The fact that $(12)(34)$ and $(13)(24)$ commute is more puzzling.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I misunderstand. $(12)$ and $(12)(34)$ are order two, how can they be powers of each other?

Comment: They are not, that's why I chose them as a better counterexample to what "goes wrong". If $y$ commutes with $x$ then $y$ permutes the orbits of $x$, that seems to me where you need to start.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am very confused by your comment. $(12)$ commuting with $(12)(34)$ is my counterexample, I chose them, not you. Regardless, I'm going to think more about your second point and will update here.

Comment: I think your counterexample is not a good illustration of the difficulties, because in your case the two permutations both cut the points into two blocks, and on each block one is a power of the other - this is an  obvious possibility. But my example shows it is rather more complicated, the orbits of one may be permuted by the other.